# Flutter flutter_tts not working anymore on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, text-to-speech

I use the flutter_tts plugin in a little Flutter app. It worked but now (since I upgraded Xcode?), text to speech does not work anymore in IOS Simulator.
I upgraded Xcode to Xcode 15 and use the IOS 17.0 simulator.

My code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getLanguages();
    getVoices();
    initTts();
    choixQuestion();
    super.initState();
  }
```

with

```
void initTts()async {
    await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
    await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
    await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(1.0);
    await flutterTts.setLanguage("fr-FR");
    await flutterTts.setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playback, [
      IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker
    ]);
  }

  Future getLanguages() async {
    languages = List<String>.from(await flutterTts.getLanguages);
    for(var element in languages!){
      print(element);
    }
  }

  Future getVoices() async {
    voices = List<Object>.from(await flutterTts.getVoices);
    for(var element in voices!){
      print(element);
    }
  }

  void lectureQuestion(question)async {
    await flutterTts.speak(question);
    await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
    setState(() {
      premierBuild = false;
    });
  }
```

and

```
Future<void> choixQuestion()async{
    await onPrendListeQuestion(); // On charge les questions de la variable questionQuelquechose (qui avait été populée dans homepage) dans la variable questionnaire
    numeroQuestion = Random().nextInt(questionnaire.keys.length);
    print("longueur questionnaire avant : ${questionnaire.keys.length}");
    setState(() {
      question = questionnaire.keys.elementAt(numeroQuestion);
      reponse = questionnaire.values.elementAt(numeroQuestion);
      questionnaire.remove(question);
      nombreQuestion = nombreQuestion + 1;
    });
    await onAdapteQuestionnaireBase(); // On efface la variable questionQqchose et on la re-rempli avec la variable questionnaire

    lectureQuestion(question);
    print("longueur questionnaire après : ${questionnaire.keys.length}");
  }
```

It works with the Android simulator but not with the iOS simulator.

I red what follows on GitHub:

> You need to download languages for it to work inside of simulators.
> For IOS 16 simulator, go settings -> Spoken content -> Voices ->
> Select any language and download.

But don't find Spoken content on the IOS 17 simulator.

Thanks for your Help !